# How do I do a Linq outer join

Tags: linq, left-join

I have a repository that contains all the values I want

We'll call it `fieldsRepo`
I then have an entity that contains field values.  We'll call it `entity.FieldValues`

I need to write a query to get all the fields from `fieldsRepo`, and their value from `entity.FieldValues` if it exists.

How do I write this as LINQ with a left join, this is going to filter out where the entity doesn't contain field.  I want them to still be included.

```
var query = from field in fieldsRepo
            join entityField in entity.FieldValues
                on field.Id equals entityField.FieldId
            select new { ... };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use DefaultIfEmpty

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx

```
var query = from person in people
                    join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
                    from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (subpet == null ?       String.Empty : subpet.Name) };
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `join .. into` (i.e. GroupJoin). Each joined group will contain related to field values (if any)

```
var query = from field in fieldsRepo
            join entityField in entity.FieldValues
                on field.Id equals entityField.FieldId into g
            select new { 
                field.Id,
                ValuesCount = g.Count()
            };
```